# How to generate automatically SRI Hash in .net framework 4.7.2

Tags: html, .net-framework-version, auto-generate, subresource-integrity

In Security Scan, The third-party links/scripts don't have integrity attribute for the browser, so i want to generate SRI Hash in automatically for security purpose.

I need to Generate SRI Hash automatically in .net framework.
But,i found for .net core like below but not for .net framework.

https://programmingcsharp.com/generate-sri-hash-for-client-libraries-asp-net/

Tried, Generated SRI hash in manually and used in HTML lik below, its working for me.

[Generated SRI hash and updated in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YfFZ.png)

But I need to generate SRI Hash in automatically and used in html like above.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague recently asked for the same, and I found this https://github.com/halotron/AspNetMvcSubResourceIntegrityHelper from github for **non .net core** version. I hope this could help you and others.